# Django + Jinja. Can't choose an element of dictionary

Tags: django, jinja2

There is a dictinary of lists which I can render in Jinja template with that:

```
{{ data.production_report.main_info }}
```

So the Jinja template shows it:

```
{"product_list":[{"name":"Mushroom soup","amount_got":"10"}],"decreasing_product_list":[{"name":"Chicken meat","amount_used":"6","amount_got":"3","loss_ratio":"50%"}]}
```

The problem is that Jinja template can't render next things:

```
{{ data.production_report.main_info.product_list }}
{{ data.production_report.main_info.decreasing_product_list }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the values in product_list and decreasing_product_list is list.

This means that, you need to loop through and access the dictionaries in that list first to access the keys in that dictionary.

```
{% for product in  data.production_report.main_info.product_list %}
    <p>{{ product.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ product.amount_got }}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% for product in  data.production_report.main_info.decreasing_product_list %}
    <p>{{ product.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ product.amount_used }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```